# MYSQL Delete multiple or single row from different columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete a post I have created, but that post could also have likes or comments.

So obviously I want to be able to delete those comments or likes if I try to delete the post!

Now I have some code which is kind of working.

This code:

```
DELETE p, a, n
            FROM Posts p
            INNER JOIN Activity a ON a.uuidPost = p.uuid
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Notifications n ON n.uuidPost = p.uuid
            WHERE p.uuid = '$uuid'
```

Deletes the post, but only if there is some activity(for ex. likes or comments), but if there are no likes or comments It does not delete the post...

I could do with some help trying to understand why this is happening if possible?!

Many thanks in advance to anyone that can spare some time for me!

Comment: `INNER JOIN` only finds rows if they match in both tables. That's the difference between `INNER JOIN` and `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar Hello, so what would you recommend? I just change the 'INNER JOIN' to 'OUTER JOIN' and it worked... Would that be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `INNER JOIN`, it only returns rows that have matches between the two tables, and `DELETE` only deletes rows that are returned by the `JOIN`. If you want to delete posts even if they have nothing matching in `Activity`, you should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` -- this will return rows from the first table even if they have no matches.

```
DELETE p, a, n
FROM Posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Activity a ON a.uuidPost = p.uuid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Notifications n ON n.uuidPost = p.uuid
WHERE p.uuid = '$uuid'
```

BTW, if you declare `uuidPost` as foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, you don't need to use the joins at all -- the `CASCADE` option automatically deletes the related rows in those tables when you delete the post.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot, your second option sounds interesting...Would you recommend changing my current query? or would they work exactly the same?